# GoldenEye Wii splitscreen online?

Tags: nintendo-wii, goldeneye-007

I was wondering if GoldenEye 007 for the Wii supports online play for 2 people on the same console? Could my wife and I play online at the same time from the same console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer: Online play requires one console per player.**

[This article](http://www.nintendojo.com/games/previews/goldeneye-007-wii-multiplayer-preview) was written by someone who has played both versions of multiplayer:

> Players can also enjoy a TV screen by themselves and jump on Nintendo Wi-Fi Connection to battle with up to 8 players.
>
> “[Online and split-screen] are basically two different flavors of multiplayer, so you have a reason to play both,”

which leads to believe that the two types of multiplayer are distinct - an online mode, and a splitscreen mode. While local multiplayer is splitscreen, it appears as though online multiplayer is restricted to singlescreen.

Comment: I agree it does make someone lean towards believing that it does not support this capability. However, i am looking for a confirmation. I dont believe the wii has this type of power to do this, but i was just wondering. If it does, we are going to go out and buy immediately. Thanks